# Abrir imagens de uma pasta de um servidor externo no android

Tags: android, imageview

Ola, tenho uma pasta com imagens em um servidor externo, tem como pegar o link dessa pasta e abrir as imagens que estao nela(tipo slide) em uma activity no caso no android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode recuperar a imagem através de um InputStream e usar o [BitmapFactory.decodeStream ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) para criar um bitmap apartir do InputStream, e depois usar o [setImageBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) para o image view mostrar a imagem.

Mas eu pessoalmente usaria o [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) para acelerar esse processo.

Comment: mas usando o InputStream ele consegue pegar imagens de uma pasta somente por o link da pasta? por exemplo www.meusite.com.br/ImagensLegais  ae carregar as imagens que tem nessa pasta

Comment: se eu colocar as imagens em um banco de dados vai demorar muito, porque sao muita imagens, entao tava pensando nessa ideia da pasta, mas nao sei como fazer

Comment: Eu listaria os arquivos da pasta filtrando por imagens, depois baixaria elas ou usava o glide pra poder listar no imageview rapidamente

Comment: a minha maior duvida Samuel é nessa parte  " listaria os arquivos da pasta filtrando por imagens" porque to usando o banco de dados Firebase, entao eu colocaria os link das pastas com imagens lá, mas ae como vou passar para o android e ele entender que é pra ver as imagens que tem na pasta?

Comment: O seu site é feito em php? se sim eu criaria um json na pasta das imagens, sempre que fosse efetuado um envio de uma imagem para o servidor eu adicionaria o caminho dela em um array no json, depois baixaria esse json com o android e recuperaria esse array com as urls. Mas se vai usar o firebase, creio que isso possa lhe ajudar: http://javasampleapproach.com/android/firebase-storage-get-list-files-display-image-firebase-ui-database-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app

Comment: Samuel tenho um servidor linux onde esta armazenados as fotos e uns pdfs, nao estou armazenando diretamente no Firebase por questao financeira porque os arquivos estao chegando a 30gb, e nesse servidor eu ganhei esse espaço,cadastrei cada link dos pdfs no firebase database ,o app lista esses pdfs e abre no aplicativo até ae tudo bem, mas tambem tenho essas pastas com imagens, e como sao muitas eu iria perder muito tempo colocando uma por uma no firebase,

Comment: por isso estou procurando um soluçao de apenas pegar o link da pasta no servidor linux e jogar no firebase e o aplicativo varrer essas pasta e lista as imagens, nao tenho site, apenas o servidor linux e o firebase que ta pegando os pdfs e jogando no aplicativo. conseguiu entender?

Comment: quero fazer assim:
registre o link da pasta de exemplo 192.57.14.25/ww/images
e o aplicativo varre a pasta e lista as imagens que ela contém

Comment: conseguir fazer o json e estou recebendo as urls em string, como converter para imagem?

Comment: Com JSONObject https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject Exemplo de um site: http://www.matera.com/blog/post/receber-dados-via-json-em-um-aplicativo-android